# ViewPager inside BottomSheet with variable number of tabs causes a weird behavior. What might be wrong?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, bottom-sheet

I have a bottom sheet containing a view pager with a variable number of tabs. There can be either 1 tab or 2 tabs. Tab (1) is optional and does not always appear & has a recyclerview inside. Tab (2) is a normal fragment with no complex views & is always on.

Now when I initialize the viewpager with both (1) & (2), everything works fine.
But when I initialize it with (2) only, The bottom sheet stops working & I can't slide it up.

I have read some other questions that mention an inherit problem with adding a viewpager to a bottom sheet. But I can't relate to any of them regarding my case.

Can anyone think of a cause for this behavior?

Edit / solution: 
I managed to solve this issue for now.
I found that fragments added to viewpager inside bottomsheet, at least one of them has to be scroll-able.
So, my solution was to reimplement the fragment layout to have NestedScrollView as the root view. Which might not be ideal.

If anyone has more insight into this issue, I would like an explanation :)

Comment: _The bottom sheet stops working & I can't slide it up_. Where is stacktrace?

Comment: There is no stacktrace as there is not crash or any exception or error thrown. Swiping the bottom sheet up does not open it.